# what is the meaning of ' games' in this sentence?

Tags: sentence-meaning

What is the meaning of ' games' in this sentence?

> "There are shelves at the top of my closet.  I keep **games** up there".

The topic of the conversation is a description of somebody's bedroom and I struggle to explain what "games" is present for.

Comment: Video games perhaps.

Comment: Games (parlor games) come in boxes, and people store those boxes on top of closets when the closets are stand-alone closets.

Comment: Thank you all you guys. In my bedroom, my stand-alone closet are full of clothes, socks, and my sister's bras inside.

Comment: @Lam I'd say it's somewhat more likely to mean in the upper portion of a conventional closet (not stand-alone), such as on a shelf above where clothes are normally hung. Otherwise, it would probably have read *on top of.*

Comment: I'm voting to keep the question open because there are multiple definitions of *game* that might reasonably present a difficulty to an ELL in answering the question by looking it up in a dictionary. There is at least enough contextual information included to warrant reasonable assumptions in answering.

Answer (score 5):

Most likely board games, Risk, Monopoly, Catan.

Comment: Someone from Vietnam might not be familiar with those. The generic term is parlor games.

Comment: Thank you all you guys,your comments motivate me a lot in my study of english.

Comment: @Lambie Board game is also a generic term for parlor game.  These days few people have parlors so I chose the more common name.  Nguyen I would suggest using "board game" over parlor game.

Comment: I agree, board game is alright, it's that he may not know those brand-name games, that is really what I meant. :)